# PJsip Extract the value of header from a sip method

Tags: sip, pjsip

```
  NOTIFY sip:98901@xx.xx.xx.xx SIP/2.0
    To: sip:98901@xx.xx.xx.xx:1234
    From: sip:sipsak@xx.xx.xx.xx
    CSeq: 1 NOTIFY
    Call-ID:1234
    Event: check-sync;reboot=false
```

I want to Extract event header with the connected string check-sync;reboot=false

Comment: What language are you using?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to deal with an custom header, a bit similar to your case. It may help you.

You'll have to start with *`init_parser`*. Here SIP messages are parsed. Add your own custom function here. Add an element in *`pjsip_rx_data`* and store the result. This information will be passed downstream. Finally implement your stuff here *`pres_process_rx_notify`*

Answer (score 1):

```
pj_str_t event_hdr_name = pj_str("Event");
pjsip_generic_string_hdr *event_hdr = (pjsip_generic_string_hdr*)pjsip_msg_find_hdr_by_name(message, &event_hdr_name, NULL);
if (event_hdr == NULL)
    return NULL;
pj_str_t event_value = event_hdr->value;`
```

Comment: pjsip_generic_string_hdr doesn't have member value, this should be hvalue.

Comment: One more thing to note: each header has its own memory layout so casting to generic string header may not work for particular header name (let say, "max forwards"). See that list as an example http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSIP__MSG__HDR.htm